# Kotlin, RxJava, Retrofit2 Calling API but returns 2 different JSON problems

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I have a retrofit problem.

Build retrofit api class like this

```
@POST("account/login")
@FormUrlEncoded
fun login(
        @Field("Grant_Type", encoded = true) Grant_Type: String,
        @Field("username", encoded = true) Username:String,
        @Field("password", encoded = true) Password:String): Observable<Login>
```

Calling this api;

```
override fun login(username: String, password:String) {
    try{
        disposable.add(api.login("password", username, password)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .onErrorResumeNext( Observable.empty() )
                .retry()
                .subscribe {
                    loginApi ->
                        toastyInfo(loginApi.aaaaaa.toString())
                        Log.e(TAG, loginApi.aaaaaa)
                }
            )
    }catch (e: Exception){
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
    }
}
```

It works fine when I enter the correct information into the login API. I set my models accordingly. But when the login information is not correct, the login API returns different results.

My model needs to change, how do I do it or how to read the error code from the incoming json info

Returns 5 fields in my correct json file, if it is wrong 2 fields are turning.

if the input information is correct, if the normal is wrong how to read the wrong json?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can define 2 different entities. Set String or JsonObject (if you use GSON with retrofit) as response type of request. After response is retrieved - check it, and convert to corresponding entity.
2. Define a single entity which contains all fields (don't forget to mark them as **nullable**), from both types of response.

Comment: I've tried two ways. If the information is correct, it works. If it is wrong, 400 Bad Request is being called.

Comment: @ResulBal so you need a way to handle a RetrofitError, but not a different response?  https://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2016-03-16-retrofit2-rxjava-error-handling.html

Comment: If a request code is 200, but response body changed, both of suggested variants should work.

Comment: If username and password is correct, request code is 200. Wrong username and password is request code is 400